# QtCreator unable to find Qxt headers on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, libqxt

I'm working on a Qt5/QtQuick/QML application that's supposed to use QxtGlobalShortcut for hotkey control when the application is hidden or out of focus. I've been developing it using QtCreator on Linux, and I'm not entirely familiar with Linux development so I may have missed something simple.

First off, I tried cloning the master branch of the Qxt git repo [from here](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/user_guide). But for some reason *./configure* failed to create a makefile according to an error that I was getting from *make* and *make install*. I'm not very experienced in building other people's projects/libraries from source, and the output I was getting from *./configure* wasn't specific enough for me to figure out what was going on..

So instead, I decided to grab *libqxt-dev* from (X)ubuntu's APT repo. After it finished installing I added these lines to the bottom of my QtCreator project file:

```
INCLUDEPATH = usr/include

CONFIG  += qxt
QXT     += core gui
```

After setting up a basic global shortcut based totally off the Qxt documentation's example. I got a few compilation errors. First of all, the Qxt seem to use:

```
#include <QxtGlobalShortcut>
```

But QtCreator couldn't find that file, so I changed it to this:

```
#include <qxt/QxtGui/QxtGlobalShortcut>
```

Now it could find the Global Shortcut class header, and QtCreator stopped grumbling at me. Unfortunately, upon compilation QtCreator shot out this error message:

```
/usr/include/qxt/QxtGui/qxtglobalshortcut.h:28: error: qxtglobal.h: No such file or directory
```

I think this is caused by a problem in my project's INCLUDE path or something, but even having tried changing my projects INCLUDE path to this:

```
INCLUDEPATH = usr/include
        usr/include/qxt/QxtCore
        usr/include/qxt/QxtGui

CONFIG  += qxt
QXT     += core gui
```

I still get the *same error message that QxtGlobal.h (which is being #included in QxtGlobalShortcut.h) can't be found*.. 
So, I'm really not sure what I've done wrong, and I'm out of ideas about how to fix this.
Hopefully someone can help me understand what step I've skipped so that I can continue coding! Thanks!

EDIT: Here's what I have for my entire Qt project .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    Gamepad.cpp \
    Script.cpp \
    System.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    Gamepad.h \
    Script.h \
    System.h

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lSDL2

CONFIG  += qxt
QXT     += core gui
```

Everything before LIBS was automatically generated by QtCreator for my project. I added the LIBS, CONFIG, and QXT elements as per the user instructions for SDL2 and Qxt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big problem here:

```
INCLUDEPATH = usr/include
```

1) You are using relative path from the current working directory, so not `/usr/include` from the root of the filesystem.

2) You are deleting everything in the INCLUDEPATH because you set rather than append with `+=`.

3) It is unnecessary to add that line anyway since /usr/include will be looked up by default.

4) Even if it was not, you have `#include "qxtglobal.h"` instead of `#include <qxtglobal.h>`.

I would suggest to delete that line and then it should just work.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried deleting that line and it still failed with the same error. I'll update my post with an exact copy of my .pro Qt project file. Unfortunately the `#include "qxtglobal.h"` isn't part of my code, but it's part of the QxtGlobalShortcut class from the Qxt library that I'm trying to use.

Comment: @MrKatSwordfish: remove `-L/usr/lib`, too... Obviously, you have also have to re-run qmake, and if your libqxt is built against Qt 4, you will not be able to use Qt 5 anyway.

Comment: I removed that line also. Still having issues though.. I just grabbed libqxt-dev from my distro's (Xubuntu 64bit 14.4) repository. Is there any way I can check which version of Qt it supports? I had problems building libqxt from source earlier, as I mentioned above. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @MrKatSwordfish: `ldd -r /usr/lib/..` -> Check that for one binary, but it is likely Qt 4. It is Qt 4 even on the bleeding edge Archlinux.